# How can I disable HTTP Methods for Tomcat 5.5.27

Tags: http, tomcat, http-method

Please let me know how can I disable HTTP MEthods like OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE for the web server Apache Coyote HTTP 1.1 Connector (Tomcat 5.5.27)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling PUT TRACE DELETE request in Apache Tomcat 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320959/disabling-put-trace-delete-request-in-apache-tomcat-6-0)

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question for [Tomcat 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320959/disabling-put-trace-delete-request-in-apache-tomcat-60). I believe it is also applicable for Tomcat 5.5. Have also a look at this [thread](http://marc.info/?l=tomcat-user&m=110940068226551&w=2).