# Disable HTTP methods in Tomcat

Tags: security, http, tomcat

I have read these questions on disabling a list of methods in Tomcat:

- [How can I disable HTTP Methods for Tomcat 5.5.27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323241/how-can-i-disable-http-methods-for-tomcat-5-5-27)
- [Disabling PUT TRACE DELETE request in Apache Tomcat 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320959/disabling-put-trace-delete-request-in-apache-tomcat-6-0)

But is there a way to return a 405 response instead of a 403 response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a servlet filter that checks the request method and sends a 405 response if the method is on a blacklist.